# How to force dhcpcd to forget an old static address after editing dhcpcd.conf?

Tags: debian, networking, ip

How can I force `dhcpcd` to forget a previously configured static address after setting a new one in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

I changed:

```
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
```

to

```
static ip_address=192.168.1.2/24
```

After `/etc/init.d/dhcpcd restart` dhcpcd restarts, reads the new configuration and adds `192.168.1.2` as machine IP address, however it does not forget an old one `192.168.1.1`. The machine is accessible using both addresses until full system restart.

As I use static addresses not DHCP, suggestions to remove current leases like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151958/how-to-make-dhclient-forget-its-last-dhcp-lease) do not apply.

I also tried `/etc/init.d/networking reload` but it does improve the situation either.

Comment: What happens if you try `dhclient -r $interface` and `dhclient $interface`, where `$interface` is the name of your network interface.

Comment: Trying `dhclient -r eth0 ; dhclient eth0` via SSH I loose connectivity on all addresses.